# I am Unable to use "org.elasticsearch.aggregations.pipeline.BucketSelectorPipelineAggregationBuilder" in elastic search 8.9.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

In maven repo inside the elasticsearch-8.9.2.jar, I am not able to find aggregations folder which contains BucketSelectorPipelineAggregationBuilder class.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/8.9.2/

When I included this library in my project I am not getting aggregations folder.

I searched in maven repo for any other library which can include aggregations folder I couldn't find.

But this folder is present in zip file of elastic search 8.9.2

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-8-9-2